# Force aplication to go to previous view without a button xcode

Tags: xcode, view, back

I have created an application that if the page cannot load, it gives an error message. However, after that, it just shows a blank white screen. How can I edit the code so that it will automatically go to the previous view?

Comment: It depends...what code do you use to get to the current one?

Comment: Just a Navigation Controller. No code.

Comment: **Something** causes it to be there....  A push segue, perhaps?  It's OK to give hints even if you don't want to come out and tell people what's actually going on in the program.

Comment: It is a push segue. I thought that that meant nothing as I did not have to input code to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Call popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated method of the UINavigationController if page cannot load.

Answer (score 0):

My guess that what would work for you would be after the alert do something like:

```
if(butttonIndex == 1){

      Previous_View *next=[[Previous_View alloc] initWithNibName:@"Previous_View" bundle:nil];

      [self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this after your message:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

or if you want to jump back to the root view:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```